# Laravel getting collection delete nothing

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am sending collection of id's `by checkbox` to my controller to delete them  all together, **I get network `200` but nothing will delete**.

`javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#multidel').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('admin/delmultipleproducts') }}',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('.productsfordel:checked').serialize(),
        success:function(data) {
          console.log('done');
        }
      });

      $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
          alert('successfully deleted.');
          window.location.reload();
      });

    });
  });
</script>
```

`controller`

```
public function multipledel(Request $request){

        $product = Product::where('id', $request->productsfordel);
        if(!empty($product->suboptions)){
          $product->suboptions()->detach();
        }
        if(!empty($product->subspecifications)){
          $product->subspecifications()->detach();
        }
        if(!empty($product->relatives)){
          $product->relatives()->detach();
        }
        if(!empty($product->imageOne)){
          Storage::delete($product->imageOne);
        }
        if(!empty($product->imageTwo)){
          Storage::delete($product->imageTwo);
        }
        $product->delete();

      // Session::flash('success', 'Selected products are successfully deleted.');
      // return redirect()->route('products.index');
    }
```

`route`

```
  Route::post('delmultipleproducts', 'ProductController@multipledel')->name('delmultipleproducts');
```

any idea why is that?

## UPDATE

if i change my ajax data to `serialize()` instead of `val()` i get

```
array:3 [
  0 => "35"
  1 => "34"
  2 => "33"
]
```

and when i delete then only `id = 35` will delete, `only one of them instead of all of them.

Comment: Have you checked what you are getting in `$request->productsfordel`?

Comment: @MuhammadNauman if i change my ajax data to `serialize()` instead of `val()` i get `array:3 [
  0 => "35"
  1 => "34"
  2 => "33"
]`

Comment: @MuhammadNauman my apologize , I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an array of IDs. So this would work.

```
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $request->productsfordel)->get();
foreach($products as $product){
  $product->suboptions()->detach();
  $product->subspecifications()->detach();
  $product->relatives()->detach();
  if(!empty($product->imageOne)){
      Storage::delete($product->imageOne);
    }
  if(!empty($product->imageTwo)){
    Storage::delete($product->imageTwo);
  }
  $product->delete();
}
```

Or you could do all this in Laravel observables and in here just write

```
Product::whereIn('id', $request->productsfordel)->delete();
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'product_relatives' (SQL: select `product_relatives`.*, `product_relatives`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `product_relatives`.`relatives_id` as `pivot_relatives_id` from `product_relatives` inner join `product_relatives` on `product_relatives`.`id` = `product_relatives`.`relatives_id` where `product_relatives`.`product_id` = 32)`

Comment: i think i should cascade `relatives_id` :) let me try

Comment: Thats what I was going to suggest :)

Comment: solved :) as i'm using cascade i don't need detach methods so i removed all except deleting my images and working like charm :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are returning the collection here -

`$product = Product::where('id', $request->productsfordel);`

You should actually return the first product,

`$product = Product::where('id', $request->productsfordel)->get()->first();`

OR if you are sure it's indexed on a primary key (i.e your id is a primary key

You should do

`$product = Product::find($request->productsfordel);`

OR if you want to 
delete all the products according to request

```
foreach($request->productsfordel as $id) {
 $product = Product::find($id);
        if(!empty($product->suboptions)){
          $product->suboptions()->detach();
        }
        if(!empty($product->subspecifications)){
          $product->subspecifications()->detach();
        }
        if(!empty($product->relatives)){
          $product->relatives()->detach();
        }
        if(!empty($product->imageOne)){
          Storage::delete($product->imageOne);
        }
        if(!empty($product->imageTwo)){
          Storage::delete($product->imageTwo);
        }
        $product->delete();
```

Comment: Yup, it seems like you want to delete all of them check my updated answer

Comment: again error `500` and delete nothing not even one of them.

Comment: Maybe you are getting empty `$product` you can try updating ` $product = Product::findOrFail($id);`

Comment: i tried this `$products = Product::whereIn('id', $request->productsfordel)->get();
        dd($products);` and it returns all my 3 selected products data.

Comment: solved :) as i'm using cascade i don't need detach methods so i removed all except deleting my images and working like charm :)